# How do I turn off the "Running in software rendering mode" warning?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, cinnamon, webgl

I'm running Arch Linux/Cinnamon in Virtual Box on a Windows 7 machine. One of the technologies I need to use is WebGL. For whatever reason (that's a different issue), WebGL will not work when Display->Screen->Enable 3D Acceleration is enabled in Virtual Box. As a result, I've turned off 3D Acceleration, and am able to use WebGL just fine.

When I boot, though, I get a warning telling me I am running in software rendering mode. Is there some way to disable this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been searching for an answer to this, and the best I can do is go to System Settings > Notifications and turn "Enable notifications" off. This does not actually disable it but puts it in the systray area.

Comment: Hopefully we'll get a better answer eventually, but thi does work. The problem is it turns off other notifications, too, and some of those might be good to see.

Answer (score 3):

I found a more targeted solution [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2159). In short: Just comment out or remove the `notifyCinnamon2d();` line in `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Cinnamon notices that only software rendering is available but the 2D mode isn't set implicitly.
(See @Zoltan's answer)

```
if (software_rendering && !GLib.getenv('CINNAMON_2D')) {
    notifyCinnamon2d();
}
```

in `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.js`

The easiest (and probably intended way) to get rid of this warning is selecting software rendering mode in the logon screen:

[image: Logon Screen]
[image: Rendering Mode Selection]

Answer (score 0):

Be careful editing **main.js**!! You could really screw things up, maybe make a backup copy first if you're going to try this:

`cp /usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.js /usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.bak.js
sudo nano /usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.js`

Press F6 to search and search for *notifyCinnamon2d*..

Literally just comment out this function call ***notifyCinnamon2d*** as per my screenshot link *(Which I can't post because I'm under the limit to be able to post screenshots)*

https://i.postimg.cc/SQZPtVVp/sshot.jpg

Enjoy!